# Are there any implementations of Kmeans with Cosine distance in Apache Spark/PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, distance, k-means, trigonometry

Are there any working implementations of KMeans with Cosine distance applied to a Tf-IDF processed data frame in Apache Spark?

Spark, of course has Euclidean distance implementation in the ml library, but not so for any other distance measures.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented my own version of k-means on top of spark which uses standard TF-IDF vector representation and (-ve) cosine similarity as the distance metric [code snippet for reference](https://gist.github.com/rajanim/e01d1af591d697202c75ee0a785fa94f).  The results from this k-means look right, not as skewed as spark k-means. [figure 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkcIZ.png)
Additionally, I experimented by plugging in Euclidean distance as a similarity metric (into my own version of k-mean) and results continue to look right, not at all as skewed as spark k-means. Results indicate that its not issue with distance measure but some other case with spark's k-means implementation(scala mllib)

Comment: How you to put in the cosine metric into kmeans function?

Comment: Since the distance metric function is a private method in spark kmean, any other metrics(cosine for that matter) cannot be plugged in. 
And fwiw, its not an issue with distance metric but some bug in kmean implementation itself, I experimented with both distance metrics(cosine as well as euclidean) in my own custom kmean implementation(developed on top of spark) and get better quality clusters unlike spark kmean.

Comment: UPDATE (May 2019): Spark 2.4 now supports Cosine distance in KMeans, see
[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans@setDistanceMeasure(distanceMeasure:String):KMeans.this.type), using spark.mllib.clustering.DistanceMeasure class. Apart from that, could you please mention what bugs did you find in KMeans? Maybe due to initialization? (Spark also has a boosted clusters initialization following KMeans++)

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize your vectors and then cosine similarity or Euclidean distance will give same results. Mathematically it is easy to see that the Euclidean distance = 2 (1 - Cosine Similarity) for normalized vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The KMeans algorithm is based on Euclidean distance, and can not directly use cosine distance. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81481/why-does-k-means-clustering-algorithm-use-only-euclidean-distance-metric) is a good explanation of this fact:

> K-Means is implicitly based on pairwise Euclidean distances b/w data points, because the sum of squared deviations from centroid is equal to the sum of pairwise squared Euclidean distances divided by the number of points.

If you wish to use cosine distance (or any other metric), [KMedoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) might be a good option. It is similar to KMeans, but uses the median, instead of the mean, in it's update step. This allows the use of arbitrary distance metrics.

Answer (score 0):

A late update incase anyone runs into this.  Current versions of spark kmeans do implement cosine distance function, but the default is *euclidean*.  For pyspark, this can be set in the constructor:

```py
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans

km = KMeans(distanceMeasure='cosine', k=2, seed=1.0)
# or via setter
km.setDistanceMeasure('cosine')
```

[pyspark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans.distanceMeasure)

---

For Scala use the setter:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans

val km = new KMeans()
km.setDistanceMeasure("cosine")
```

[Scala docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/clustering/KMeans.html#distanceMeasure:org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param%5BString%5D)

Note that an exception will be thrown if there are any zero vectors in the feature vector.